# Extract randomly located word with certain number of characters from sentence

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to extract a 4 characters word from sentences in every cell. This word unfortunately is located in random position in the data.

I have these sets of data:

```
A2: WKDOASPD A4IT LKALOASPDO
A3: 12JK ASDPPQDKL MMAKALSDKOQ
A4: WEL 1H9L AKSDOKQPWDP
```

And I'd like to have a column next to it with these data:

```
B2 : A4IT
B3 : 12JK
B4 : 1H9L
```

Is there any formula to do this?

Comment: is it the only 4 letter word in the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has it one can use FILTERXML:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[string-length(.) =4]")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.. 
It works for some sets of data. I just found out there are other datas where this 4 characters word followed by punctuation (can be ) or - or ,). Is there modification to this formula since this one only works for data without punctuation?

Comment: Use nested substitutes to replace all those characters with nothing: `""`